# What does Thread Safety mean?

Tags: ruby, thread-safety

I've been reading some blogs on multi-threaded programming in ruby. What I noticed is that the author tends to use the word thread-safety. What does it mean? Why is it important to write thread-safety code?

Comment: +1 for thinking about what you're reading, not everyone does :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a resource (let's say a global List of Books for example) and you have two threads running which can modify this list. There are a lot of situations where the data of the list will get inconsistent.

- (Thread A reads a Book ands displays its Data)
- (Thread B deletes the same Book while the Data is used by Thread A)
- (Thread A now wants to add some information to the Book)

So you have to make your code **thread-safe** so that at anytime only one single thread can have write access to the list of books.

**Deadlocking** mentioned by SpyrosP happens when Thread A blocks the List for writing and waits for Thread B to add data on the list. Because both threads will wait for each other to do something they can't do. That only happens if the thread-safety mechanism is not properly implemented.

Comment: Very well explained. +1 Let me also add that most ready made packages (like Queue for Python) are based on thread safe mechanisms out of the box.

Comment: @SpyroP Good point! You'll find a lot of ready made Thread Safety data structures in many programming languages. I'm pretty sure some of ruby's Lists and Maps also care about that.